# Error when restart elasticsearch-full bty brew

Tags: java, elasticsearch, homebrew, magento2

I run cmd "brew services restart elasticsearch-full" and have this problems. Anyone help me ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxfAp.png)
I try Move to trash and cancel but it's still not working. I also try sudo too
I try to install native for project magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You can either switch to Intel chip Mac or follow this step to replace JDK
https://gist.github.com/todgru/0ba097d63318313f12a52594217f8e2b